# abstract with 2 base classes..what is the use of abstract class here in the issue mentioned below

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am a java learner..doing exercises from web..

I have an abstract class X and 2 subclasses Y and Z.

Y needs to have an int and should be able to set and get int.
Z needs to have an arraylist of integers and should be able to get and set it.

My need is to have one object of the baseclass and then make use of either Y or Z alone from the user input. I want to do it  the correct way.

PS: I am not sure how abstract class will help here. but that is part of the requirement..

thanks

Comment: we need to hear more about the requirement. What is the common functionality that the abstract class is supposed to provide?

Comment: Basically i am building something like a calculator..where i increment the integer or values in the integer array. Common thing is to increment..But i dont know how to make use of the abstract class to  do this ?

Comment: who asked you to use abstract class? whose design are you following?

Comment: whose design and who asked --Nobody..I want to have generic adder for Integer and Integer vector..And one object which i can use it for both the subclasses

Comment: you can not have an object of base class as you are trying to have it as "Abstract"

Comment: Like x = new Y(); this is how i want to use it..not x = new x()

Comment: @user808235. Please look up on rules of Overriding in java. That would help you design your system better in my opinion. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this (as far I can guess from the vague requirements) :

```
public abstract class AbstractCalc {
    public abstract void increment (int by);
}

public class SingleIntCalc extends AbstractCalc {
    int value = 0;

    @Override
    public void increment(int by) {
        value+=by;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}

public class MultiIntCalc extends AbstractCalc {

    private List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    public void increment(int by) {
        for (int i = 0; i <ints.size(); i++) {
            int value = ints.get(i);
            ints.set(i, (value+by));
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> getInts() {
        return ints;
    }

    public void setInts(List<Integer> ints) {
        this.ints = ints;
    }

}
```

Comment: trying your answer..Thank you very much

Comment: When i do something like AbstractCalc x = new SingleIntCalc(); I am not able to call get, set fucntions..

Comment: This is normal : the compiler looks at the reference type (here `AbstractCalc`) and sees only one method (`increment()`). If you want to be able to call the get/set methods, you'll have to either declare them in `AbstractCalc`, or use a different type of reference (eg. `SingleIntCalc calc = new SingleIntCalc()`).

Comment: BTW, it would really help us help you, if you could provide more information about that exercise.

Comment: All i wanted to do was build a facility where i can add to integers and integer arrays..So was trying to use inheritance and overriding. I can use any logic..In the main function i am taking input whether i am adding integer array or integer..but i didnt want to write a logic where i create different objects and achieve the same.

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept my answer then, so that people know that your problem has been solved.

Comment: cool my question is answered saying that cannot be done with the design i have in mind. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The requirement doesnt suit the need. But in case you had something like 
Vehicle as the base class
and two subclasses say Car and scooter

- Vehicle would have tyre as the member.
- Car would have steering as the member
- Scooter would have handle as the member

Now based on the type of vehicle you can invoke necessary class..

```
Vehicle vh;
vh = new Car();
vh = new Scooter();
```

Comment: do you think this is what he is asking?

Comment: He wants to know the mechanism of how to invoke an abstract class. Voting down without discussion is not ethical .. I feel !!

Comment: @SaurabhSinghal Can i write an abstract and add methods like add() del() and have two different objects use it..in one case it needs to return integer array and in another case an integer

Comment: You can add abstract add and del but the signature in the subclasses should be same. Both should either return int or int array as per overriding concept.